# LDAP access in AWS private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a scenario where i need to connect with LDAP from AWS container hosted in private subnet, how do i connect with it. Can we connect using NAT Gateway in private route table, or do i need to use Internet gateway and make the subnet public.

Comment: Where is the LDAP server?

Comment: It is sitting on on-prem.

Comment: Using a NAT Gateway should be sufficient to provide the container with access to the Internet. If the LDAP server is accessible via the Internet, it should be able to connect. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: The condition is that the subnet should be private with not even NAT-Gateway allowed. It is an internal applcation. Is there any way around that  as below Muhammad suggested for site-2-site VPN, but i have never worked on that, do you have any idea regarding that ?

Answer (score 0):

If your ldap is on-prem and you do not want to expose it, then you can setup site-to-site vpn and you'll be able to access the ldap from private subnet provided you have setup the correct route in the subnet's route table.

Comment: The LDAP is sitting on on-prem how do i configure the site-2-site VPN, there are many options, this will be my first time working on it, do you have any examples for how to configure that,

Comment: @sks123245, actually its not too difficult if you just follow the aws docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html